# Dual monitor not working, HP laptop, Nvidia GTX1650

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, hdmi, gpu, gpu-driver

I connected my Dell monitor to my HP laptop with HDMI. It worked fine with Win 10, but my Ubuntu 16.04 cannot detect the monitor.

I don't know what went wrong. I tried to install Nvidia drivers (ver430) but still doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with ubuntu,  please let me know if any info is needed.

Comment: BTW, in Software & Updates->Additional Drivers it shows NVIDIA Corporation:Unknown, I don't know if that means there's sth wrong with my driver.

Comment: Install `arandr`, it's a nice visual interface to enable, configure and arrange your connected monitors.

Comment: You need to install the recommended Nvidia graphics drivers. And, by the way, there's no GTX1650. Please check again then [edit] and update your question accordingly. Please do not post relevant information only in comments.

Comment: @bistoco it's a nice tool but I can not select HDMI from the list within the window

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia thanks for your advice but there is a GTX1650 card https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/graphics-cards/gtx-1650/

Comment: Sorry, my mistake for not seeing the "series 16" in the list of drivers. So, you need the very latest drivers for that card. At the time of this writing it's 430. Also for new hardware always prefer newer releases, like 18.04 LTS. Either way you have to add the graphics drivers PPA in order to be able to install the 430 driver in 16.04 or 18.04. Then your external monitors should work.

Comment: Hi @GabrielaGarcia, I did some research and installed the 430 driver before I posted this, but it doesn't help either, so I'm looking for advice here, thanks anyway!

Comment: *How* did you install the drivers? If you had to do "some research" it's very likely you ended up installing it with downloads from Nvidia and that may well be the source of your problem. Always install from the Ubuntu repositories or the graphics drivers PPA.